# Переделать формат даты в формат datetime (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, дата, datetime

есть датасет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

необходимо привести столбец "Календарный год/месяц" в формат времени datetime

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = ['янв', 'фев', 'мар', 'апр', 'май', 'июн', 'июл', 'авг', 'сен', 'окт', 'ноя', 'дек']
val = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, val))

def convert_to_dt(s):
  m = s[0:4].strip().lower()
  y = s[4:]
  return y + "-" + dictionary[m] + "-" + "1"

data['date'] = data['Календарный год/месяц'].apply(convert_to_dt)
```

Comment: это ответ или дополнение к вопросу?